# Querying from Firestore

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection called 'programme' inside this has documents called 'session-one', 'session-two' and so on for all the sessions, these all have a field called 'date'. Inside the session document there is an 'exercise' collection which finally contain documents called names after different exercises which count reps and weights.

When I fetch from Firestone I need to query the programme collection to return the document that has the current date in the 'date' field and then go to is further exercise collection.

Which I'm not quite sure how to do? as you can't call a document after a query.

Comment: Please show the relevant code

Answer (score 3):

Read operations in Firestore are shallow, so reading an programma document will **not** automatically read the nested exercises for that programma.

To read the exercises, you will need to perform an extra read operation. This can be either a separate [read operation per exercises subcollection](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_all_documents_in_a_subcollection) you want to read, or a single [collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query) across all `exercises` collections.